# Pytest command line Arguments running single parametrized test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a `pytest_generate_tests()` function that generates a number of tests. The tests compare API calls with the correct stored calls. I have command line arguments that can be set to write and overwrite tests.

Here is my `conftest.py` that generates the tests

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """Prevent new API's from being written during pipeline tests."""
    parser.addoption(
        "--write_api", action="store_true", default=False,
          help="run tests writing API to YAML"
    )
    parser.addoption(
        "--overwrite", action="store_true", default=False,
          help="overwrite existing API in YAML - must be used with --write-api"
    )


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if metafunc.config.getoption('--write_api'):
        write_api = True
    else:
        write_api = False
    if metafunc.config.getoption('--overwrite'):
        overwrite = True
    else:
        overwrite = False
    metafunc.cls.overwrite = overwrite
    metafunc.cls.write_api = write_api
    if 'device' in metafunc.cls.__dict__:
        device = metafunc.cls.__dict__['device']
        devices = metafunc.cls.__dict__[device]
        if metafunc.function.__name__ == 'test_details':
            return details_generator(metafunc, device, devices)

        elif metafunc.function.__name__ == 'test_methods':
            return method_generator(metafunc, device, devices)
```

I can add the custom command line arguments when running all tests or selecting a single non-parametrized test:

```
pytest --write-api
pytest test_all_devices.py::TestGeneralAPI::test_login --write-api
```

I receive an error when I try to run a specific parametrized test. I tried using the argument before and after the test selector with the same result.

```
pytest test_device.py::DeviceTest:test_methods["device.OSU1['update']"] --write-api
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --write-api
```

The test runs as it should without the argument:

```
pytest test_device.py::DeviceTest:test_methods["device.OSU1['update']"]
```

Is it possible to add an argument running a single parametrized test?